# Chainload Windows from initramfs

Tags: windows, initramfs

Is there any way to chainload Windows from/within initramfs ?

I am having grub on MBR. An entry in `grub.conf`, Will boot into the *initramfs*, execute some task and then boot into the windows (of-course without rebooting)

Is it possible ? Is there any way to do so ?

If target OS is Linux, then I can use switch_root, chroot or similar utilities.
But for windows, I am not sure what to use.